# How do I consolidate container disks to my main volume?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, apfs

I am using MacOs Big Sur (11.3) and recently removed my dual-boot data, hoping to use the storage on my main volume instead. However, once I did this, it left behind APFS container disks. How do I consolidate them into a single storage device?

Image for reference, main disk has 419 gb of space:
[my disk util](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moatF.png)

Apologies if this question is basic, I am still learning how to work with disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it myself, all I had to do was edit my disks from within the partition menu as opposed to in the main view. Thanks!